# Data cells "#Deleted" in Access - ODBC, MySQL and BIGINT unique ID

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I have problem with MS Access 2007 table connected via ODBC to MySQL server (not Microsoft SQL Server).

**If unique identifier in MySQL table is BIGINT - all cells content is displayed like this: "#Deleted".**

I have found this article:

["#Deleted" errors with linked ODBC tables (at support.microsoft.com)](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/128809)

and it says:

> The following are some strategies that you can use to avoid this
>   behavior:
>
> - Avoid entering records that are exactly the same except for the    unique index.
> - Avoid an update that triggers updates of both the    unique index and another field.
> - Do not use a Float field as a unique index or as part of a unique index because of the inherent rounding problems of this data type.
> - Do all the updates and inserts by using SQL pass-through queries so that you know exactly what is sent to the ODBC data source.
> - Retrieve records with an SQL pass-through query. An SQL pass-through query is not updateable, and therefore does not cause
>     "#Delete" errors.
> - Avoid storing Null values within any field making up the unique index of your linked ODBC table.

but I don't have any of these things "to avoid". My problem is in BIGINT. To make sure if this is it I created 2 tables, one with INT id, one with BIGINT. And this is it.

I can't change BIGINT to INT in my production database.

**Is there any way to fix this?**

Im using: Access 2007, mysql-connector-odbc-3.51.30-winx64, MySQL server 5.1.73.

Comment: On the "Metadata" tab of the MySQL Connector/ODBC Data Source Configuration dialog there is a "Treat BIGINT columns as INT columns" setting. Does that make any difference?

Comment: You might also have better luck with the newer v5.1 version of MySQL Connector/ODBC. v3.51 is pretty old. FWIW, I just tested with MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver v5.01.13.00 and I was able to use a linked table in Access to manipulate a MySQL table with a BIGINT Primary Key without difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

You can try basing the form on an Access query, and converting the BIGINT to an INT using CInt() in the query. This happens before the form processing. Depending on your circumstance, you may need to convert to a string (CStr()) in the Query, and then manually handle validating a user has entered a number using IsNumeric. The idea is to trick the form into not trying to interpret the datatype, which seems to be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Access 2016 now supports BigInt: https://blogs.office.com/2017/03/06/new-in-access-2016-large-number-bigint-support/

Comment: I tried using latest MS Access (Office 365). Still having this issue.

Comment: If you test this, you'll see that there a clash between what ODBC does and what Access does.  :-(   So, no, MS claims it supports bigint, but it's not implemented properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2019 and with the latest ODBC driver from Oracle (v 8.0.17) and Access 365 (v 16.0.11904), the problem still occurs.

When the ODBC "Treat BIGINT columns as INT columns" is ticked and in Access support for Bigint is enabled in options, the Linked tables with Bigint #id columns (the primary key) show as deleted. Ruby creates these by default, so we are loathe to fiddle with that.

If we disable the above two option, Access thinks the #id column bigint is a string and shows the data.  But then the field type is not bigint or int anymore.

This is quite pathetic, since this problem is almost 10 years old now.

Comment: I guess that in 2000's Office 2003 was really complete, polished and that good product that there were nothing to do. So they fired whole team who worked on Office and hired some kids to make ribbons and to remove things that they don't understand (like pivot Tables in Access). That sucks. Thankfully Office 2003 is still working in Windows 7.

Comment: I agree with you, Kamil, MS Office has steadily gone backwards.  It's way too complicated, the menus are obfuscated and the generally it's replaced precision with jello.  However, Access still provides the best GUI SQL editor that we have been able to find and we've tested a great many!

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL driver has an option to convert `BIGINT` values to `INT`. Would this solve the issue for you?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't do the trick, but even if it did, when working with numbers larger than what int supports, it creates a problem again.  So it might be a fix for small datasets, but it really needs to be addressed properly.